# Gitlab-CI.yml, requirements.txt and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gitlab, gitlab-ci, requirements.txt

I need to add Tensorflow to my requirement.txt. First I added "tensorflow" without a specific version, but in Gitlab-CI linters give me information that I need to add a specific version, so I added it and it looks like "tensorflow == 2.0.0-rc0" but in Gitlab-CI I got that:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

CI return:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.3.1)
$ pip install --upgrade setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/28/c45d8b54c1339f9644b87663945e54a8503cfef59cf0f65b3ff5dd17cf64/setuptools-42.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (583kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 41.6.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-41.6.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-41.6.0
Successfully installed setuptools-42.0.2
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting numpy==1.16.4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/4b/f9f4b96c0b1ba43d28a5bdc4b64f0b9d3fbcf31313a51bc766942866a7c7/numpy-1.16.4.zip (5.1MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

and part of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: "python:3.8"

before_script:
 - python --version
 - pip install --upgrade pip
 - pip install --upgrade setuptools
 - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: which `python` image are you using?

Comment: I using Python 3.8.0

Comment: try running `pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --upgrade setuptools && pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0`

Comment: That not work. I added install pip and setup tools to CI in before_script: and I have in requirements.txt numpy==1.16.4 and tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0. Numpy installed successfuly but tensorflow not.

Comment: Can you run `python -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'`. It'll check if your python is 32bit or 64bit

Comment: I checked and I have 64bit python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204444/discussion-between-aviad-levy-and-belluu).

Comment: tensorflow==2.0.0rc0 and tensorflow==2.0.0  or tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0 give me same error. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change image from Python 3.8 for Python 3.7 work for me. So problem is with latest Python 3.8